# flask mega tutorial, how to auto set size=32 to change with window size

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been following the flask mega tutorial and I came across this part of code. "size=32" only sets a set size for the input box so when I change my window screen to a different size, it doesn't change accordingly.

I was wondering if there is a way to replace the "size=32" with something else.

```
<h2>{{ form.username.label }}</h2>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but you _should_ be able to use `{{ form.username(style='width: 100%;') }}`

Comment: You can add a class to the field and style it in any way you want:  {{ form.username(class_="name_of_class") }}